# Cocoa mini toolbar under table (add, remove)

Tags: cocoa, toolbar

I'm trying to implement a mini toolbar under a NSTableView like I see in a lot of OS X applications, but have no idea about which widgets to use to get the final result.

As an example, take a look at the following screenshot from Mail.app:

[Mail.app http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/4729/picture1l.png](http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/4729/picture1l.png)

What is the best way to implement buttons like that? (add, config, remove, etc)

Comment: The image does not show making the question less clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [BWToolkit](http://www.brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/), a Cocoa framework that provides those types of widgets, among many others.  It even comes with an Interface Builder plugin so you can just drag and drop them directly into your window.  In particular, watch the "Create a Mail.app style interface" movie under the "Button Bars" heading on the main page.